# float div and keep it at the baseline

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I'm working on a chat module for a project, everything is working but the css. I have a global container for the chat elements, this div has fixed position. Inside I have two divs, one for the chat windows and one for the contacts list, both the chat window and the contact list are floating to the right and can be "minimized" by clicking on the title (this hides the body and only leaves the title  visible). The problem is if I minimize just one of the divs it remains on the top at the same height as the other div (see the image).

This is what I'm getting:

[image: the container in the right remains at the top of the div]

This is what I want:

[image]

Relevant code:

```
<body>
    <!--boring code-->

    <div class="chat_container">
        <div class="contactos show">
            <div class="titulo">contactos</div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="contacto online" id="contacto_3">juan an orozco</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat_wdow_container">
            <div class="chat_wdow " id="chat_wdow_3">
                <div class="title_area">juan an orozco</div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="msg_area"></div>
                    <input type="text" name="msg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and css

```
div.chat_container
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border: 1px dashed gold;
}

div.chat_container > div
{
    float: right;
}

div.chat_container div.contactos div.titulo
{
    text-align: center;
}


div.chat_container div.contactos
{
    min-width: 150px;
    background: dimgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0px;
}

div.chat_container div.contactos div.container
{
    display: none;
    min-height: 145px;
    padding: 10px;
}
div.chat_container div.contactos.show div.container
{
    display: block;
}

div.chat_container div.chat_wdow
{
    margin: 0 5px;
    min-width: 190px;
    background: dimgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0px;
    float: left;
}

div.chat_container div.chat_wdow div.title_area
{
    text-align: center;
}

div.chat_container div.chat_wdow div.container div.msg_area
{
    background-color: white;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 10px;
}

div.chat_container div.chat_wdow div.container
{
    display: none;
}

div.chat_container div.chat_wdow.show div.container
{
    display: block;
}

.chat_wdow input[type="text"]
{
    width: 186px;
}
```

To collapse the window I toggle via mootools the class `.show`. When this class is missing the container area of the windows has `display:none` and when it gets applied it has `display:block`.

What I have tried so far:

- setting the fixed parent to a height of 0 and overflow visible
- seting the inner container to position relative and the child to absolute
- using clear and overflow hacks
- changing margins to auto values
- changing vertical sizes and minimun heights of the inner containers and childs
- changing display to inline and inline block
- changing chat container to absolute and inner containers to relative

I have been searching for a while on google and SO but I have only found the options that I have already tried, I also looked at facebook's chat css but I can't find anything to help me, so I am looking for new ideas to bring down the collapsed div.

Comment: Can you create a second image or screen shot showing how the layout should look?  Specifically, when minimized, where do you want the `.title_area` to be positioned? Also are you using jQuery to show/hide the two elements (chat and contact list)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use display:inline-block or display:inline instead and then set the vertical-align:bottom.

Ex: http://jsbin.com/uhubeh/1/edit

If you know the widths of both, however, you could also just use absolute positioning.

Comment: it worked whit a few modifications,did the same for `.chat_wdow` (since the windows can be more than 1 and will be added progratically)and for `.chat_container .container` set 'text-aling:left' to let the text in its original look